# Как сделать подобную анимацию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, css-animation

Как сделать такую анимацию кнопки? Кнопка с меню [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю так, но при частом клике анимация выполняется неправильно. А в примере при частом клике появляется второй внутренний круг.

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  item.addClass("active");
  setTimeout(function(){
    item.removeClass("active");
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
@keyframes circle {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.button {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c7c7c7;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.button.active .circle {
  animation: circle  0.8s ease;
}

svg {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <div class="circle"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" fill="#606060">
    <path d="M4 8h4V4H4v4zm6 12h4v-4h-4v4zm-6 0h4v-4H4v4zm0-6h4v-4H4v4zm6 0h4v-4h-4v4zm6-10v4h4V4h-4zm-6 4h4V4h-4v4zm6 6h4v-4h-4v4zm0 6h4v-4h-4v4z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: у Вас в вашем же коде похоже вроде

Comment: У вас таймер стоит, конечно анимация при частых кликах будет начинаться сначала.

Comment: Попробуйте from { transform: scale(0); } заменить на from { transform: scale(0.8); opacity:0.8; }

Comment: посмотрите material design/ui

Comment: На mousedown вещай класс с фоном, на keyup убирай, все просто же :З

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так сделать:

```js
function click(el) {
  let circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('r', 1);
  circle.setAttribute('style', 'animation: 0.4s wave');
  el.querySelector('g').append(circle)
  setTimeout(() => circle.remove(), 400);
}
```

```css
@keyframes wave {
  from  {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(13);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-12,-12,24,24 width=100 height=100 onclick=click(this)>
  <g style="pointer-events:none"></g>
  <path d="
    M-7.5,-7.5 h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z
    M-7.5,-1.5 h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z
    M-7.5,4.5  h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z m6,0 h3v3h-3z
  "></path>
</svg>
```